# how to take image at run time and save to mysql using java

Tags: java

i want to capture screen image on run time and save to MySQL   using java ;
i try many code but fail on making jar file then come error mostly like file not found. especially i capture screen and save in a folder then i read folder then i save image to MySQL
in fact i want directly i capture screen and then i want to save to MySQL  directly, why we required to first save on hard disk then read from hard disk then save 
i want capture screen and then save directly to MySQL

i want to capture screen image on run time and save to MySQL using java ; i try many code but fail on making jar file then come error mostly like file not found. especially i capture screen and save in a folder then i read folder then i save image to MySQL 
in fact i want directly i capture screen and then i want to save to MySQL directly, why we required to first save on hard disk then read from hard disk then save i want capture screen and then save directly to MySQL

Comment: What have your tried? What have your tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, there is no need to save to file. Usually screenshots are made using some native code instead of java. You can use JNI to bind the native method and return-value into a `byte[]` in java.